# Why I am getting null JSON response?

Tags: android, json

I am fetching data from `JSON` to android.But, I am getting an empty `JSON` response. The `PHP` code which generates `JSON` data is as follows:

```php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT dbname FROM users ORDER BY dbname ASC");
//defined second array for dbnames' list
$dblist = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //array_push($response['dblist'],$row['dbname']);
    $dblist[] = array('name'=>$row['dbname']);
}
$response['dblist'] = $dblist;
```

This is the `JSON` response.

```
{"dblist":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"arsod"}]}
```

The `Java` code to fetch data in `android` is as follows:

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray names = obj.getJSONArray("dblist");

for(int i=0; i < names.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject n = names.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = n.getString("name");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    institutes.add(name);
}
```

where `institutes` is an `ArrayList` in which I want to add each fetched element. But while fetching the data, I get the error in logcat `org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`. What is going wrong?

Comment: Please Log the names JsonArray

Comment: Why are you double getting `dblist` in your Java code? You have an object `obj` which already contains an array called `dblist`. You don't need this line `JSONObject object = obj.getJSONObject("dblist");`. Just `JSONArray names = obj.getJSONArray("dblist");`

Comment: @vrdrv Just made these changes, but still problem persists

Comment: Attach a debugger.

Comment: `End of input at character 0` Your 's' variable appears to be empty or starts with invalid json characters. Debug this variable first and check your networking

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

```
JSONObject object = obj.getJSONObject("dblist");
```

and replace all occurences of `object.` with `obj.`

your `JSONObject obj` doesn't contain `"dblist"` object, there is only array inside it, so you should look for `getJSONArray("dblist")` straight inside `obj`

edit: you are parsing different `String s`, I've just checked this code:

```
final String s = "{\"dblist\":[{\"name\":\"a\"},{\"name\":\"arsod\"}]}";
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray names = obj.getJSONArray("dblist");

for (int i = 0; i < names.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject n = names.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = n.getString("name");
    Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

which is almost exacly same as your and works pretty fine...

Comment: just made the changes, but nothing happened. Problem is still there

Comment: problem is in `String s`, this is not JSON in your case... try to log or toast whole `s` before execute posted snipped

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following:

```
s = {"dblist":[{"name":"a"},{"name":"arsod"}]}
```

Your code should be like,

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray names = obj.getJSONArray("dblist");

for(int i=0; i < names.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject n = names.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = n.getString("name");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    institutes.add(name);
}
```

Comment: @Thalow Oh, first there was one more `JSONObject` written, when I checked it. You must be having enclosed this code in try, catch, have you got some exception in catch block ? I hope you have written, `printStackTrace()` in catch.

Comment: I am getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Thalow I think you should check for the line number and see what code is written there on that line, basically that variable is null for which `length()` method is being called.